# get variable value from a file and append with new

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a file which has a variable

```
 $versionNumber = "1.0.0
```

I need to change the variable value to `"$versionNumber = "user_choice"`" explicitly.

```
#------------------------------------------------
# Pack parameters used to create the .nupkg file.
#------------------------------------------------

# Specify the Version Number to use for the NuGet package. If not specified, the version number of the assembly being packed will be used.
# NuGet version number guidance: https://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning and the Semantic Versioning spec: http://semver.org/
# e.g. "" (use assembly's version), "1.2.3" (stable version), "1.2.3-alpha" (prerelease version).
$versionNumber = "1.0.0"

# Specify any Release Notes for this package. 
# These will only be included in the package if you have a .nuspec file for the project in the same directory as the project file.
$releaseNotes = ""

# Specify a specific Configuration and/or Platform to only create a NuGet package when building the project with this Configuration and/or Platform.
#   e.g. $configuration = "Release"
#        $platform = "AnyCPU"
$configuration = ""
$platform = ""
```

Any possible approach is advisable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Get-Content` cmdlet to read the file, find the versionNumber variable using a positive lookbehind regex and replace it. Finally, use the `Set-Content` cmdlet to write it back:

```
(Get-Content 'youFile.nupkg' -raw) -replace '(?<=\$versionNumber\s=).+', '"user_choice"' |
     Set-Content 'youFile.nupkg'
```

Comment: I am using this script in Jenkins and calling user_choice as a parameter. this works but new value what I see is  $versionNumber =1.0.0 
But actual replaced value should be  $versionNumber = "1.0.0" . The space and "" are missing here.

(Get-Content "C:\TestFolder\Config.ps1" -raw) -replace '(?<=\$versionNumber\s=).+', "$env:VERSION" | Set-Content "C:\TestFolder\Config.ps1"

Answer (score 0):

other solution without regex

```
(get-content "C:\temp\nuckpkg.txt").Replace('$releaseNotes = ""', '$releaseNotes = "user_choice"') | 
    set-content "C:\temp\nuckpkg.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't properly used the code suggested by Martin .

you are using `"$env:Version"` which will finally get interpreted to the variable value only... '"' are part of replace syntax.

you should use it in this way `"'$env:Version'"` .

Regards,

Kvprasoon